# if ( [instance] in [array] ) possible in ActionScript3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement

Is it possible to see if an instance is in an array variable like this?

```
var list=[];
var instance= new SomeClass();
list.push(instance);
if( instance in list){ trace("nice"); ]
```

Or do you have to run "for loop" to see if the instance is in the array? like

```
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
  if(list[i]==instance){ trace("ok"); }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
list.indexOf(instance) ;
```

It must return the index of element in array. 
If it returns `-1`, that means that the value is not found.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It was bothering me but that works perfectly.

Comment: Yes sorry, your answer was too fast it didn't let me accept right away.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that an array contains a particular item, use the [`indexOf`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#indexOf%28%29) method:

```
if (list.indexOf(instance) > -1) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Alternatively, a common shorthand for `Array.contains` is:

```
if (~list.indexOf(instance)) {
    //do stuff
}
```

The `~` operator will turn a value of `-1` to `0` (falsey) and all other values to truthy.

Comment: I didn't know there's such thing as ~ operator. It looks nicer with it, thanks